# TFSDeleteProject Command Line

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to delete 2 project site collections from TFS as a precursor to a move to Azure DevOps.

We have 4 database instances on TFS.

```
tfsdeleteproject /collection:http://<SERVERNAME>:8080/tfs/<INSTANCENAME> "PROJECTSITECOLLECTIONNAME"
```

Would someone be able to verify this is correct?  I've read some documentation on the subject, but not 100% on the role of the instance vs the site collection name.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of references to systems with multiple instances.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to delete *team projects* or *team project collections*? They are different things.

Comment: team project collections...the roots under the instance...deleting a project is easy...i can do that from the UI

Answer (score 0):

You can easily delete Team Project Collections using the Admin console on your TFS application tier. `tfsdeleteproject` is for team projects, not team project **collections**. More accurately, you can *detach* them, leaving the database alone but disconnecting the collection from your TFS instance.

However, there is no reason to delete Team Project Collections as part of a migration to Azure DevOps. One account account is equivalent to one team project collection, so if you don't want to migrate a particular team project collection, don't run the migration tool on that team project collection.

Comment: There any way to do it without being on the tfs server?   I had understood the tfs instance was mapped to a database...but maybe the tfs instance is mapped to a SQL server instance?